Independence of random variables continuous vs discrete
I've just started chapter 4 in Grimmett & Stirzaker on continuous random variables. In this chapter, the definition for independence reads: two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are called independent if $\{X\leq x\}$ and $\{Y\leq y\}$ are independent events for all $x$ and $y$. It is left as an exercise to verify that for discrete random variables this is equivalent to $\{X=x\}$ and $\{Y=y\}$ being independent for all $x$ and $y$. I'm asking for some help to verify my steps to show the implication that if $\{X\leq x\}$ and $\{Y\leq y\}$ are independent for all $x$ and $y$ then $\{X=x\}$ and $\{Y=y\}$ are independent for all $x$ and $y$. Below is my approach.
We can write the event $\{X=a, Y=b\}$ as
$$\{X=a, Y=b\}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left[\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{a-\frac{1}{i} < X \leq a\right\}\right)\bigcap \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \left\{b-\frac{1}{i} < Y \leq b\right\}\right)\right]$$
By the continuity of $\mathbb{P}$ we can now write
\begin{equation}\mathbb{P}(\{X=a, Y=b\}) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{a-\frac{1}{i} < X \leq a\right\}\right)\bigcap \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{b-\frac{1}{i}< Y \leq b\right\}\right)\right)\end{equation}
The events on the RHS are independent by our assumption, and therefore
\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(\{X=a, Y=b\}) &= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{a-\frac{1}{i} < X \leq a\right\}\right) \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\left\{b-\frac{1}{i}< Y \leq b\right\}\right)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(\{X=a\})\mathbb{P}(\{Y=b\})\end{align}
Hope that works. Would be keen to know if that's the only/easiest way to show this.

In princple, it's correct but you cannot write $\lim$ for the sequence of events (use intersection) and you really need to write ${a-1/n<X\le a}={X\le a}\setminus {X\le a-1/n}$ instead of ${a-1/n\le X\le a}$

What is meant by "this is equivalent to the definition of independence for discrete random variables"? This makes no sense to me. For any pair $(X,Y)$ of continuous random variables we always have $0 = \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y) = \mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y) = 0$, no matter if they are independent or not, so this is clearly not sufficient for independence.

@vanderWolf Thanks for your comment! I've amended the question

@user159517 That these are equivalent definitions of independence for discrete random variables. You're quite right that $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$ for all $x$ if the random variable $X$ is continuous. I'll amend the question to be more precise

For discrete $X$ with values ${x_1,x_2,\dots }$ we have ${X\le x}=\bigcup_{x_n\le x}{X=x_n},.$ Is this not a one-line proof that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets of the form ${X\le x}$ is identical to that generated by all the ${X=x_n},?$

@KurtG. I used this to show the implication in the other direction. Does it also work for the one I'm asking about here?

It works for both directions. Take what I wrote and think about by which simple sets the $\sigma$-algebra of a discrete r.v. is generated.
